# Web BLE secure connection with pairing type 'Just Works'

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, blazor, blazor-webassembly, web-bluetooth

I have a BLE device that I wish to connect to through Web Bluetooth.

The BLE device's Characteristic is set up to only return values when requested over a secure connection, the bluetooth pairing type has to be 'Just Works'.

I am using Blazor WebAssembly and a nuget called Blazm.Bluetooth, but any pure javascript solution to this is also appreciated.
https://github.com/EngstromJimmy/Blazm.Bluetooth

I am able to get the requestDevice modal to show up in the browser, successfully pair to the device, and set up a notification handler that listens to changes in the characteristics value.

When I try to read a value from the device I get a response code telling me that I am not authorized to access data, since the device is setup to only allow access over a secure connection.

This leads me to the conclusion that a secure connection has not been established.

I am able to communicate with the device (in a different project) using the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth library, so I am certain that the device is working as expected once a secure connection has been established.

code for request:

```
export async function requestDevice(query)
{
    var objquery = JSON.parse(query);
    console.log(query);

    var device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(objquery);
    await device.gatt.connect();
    device.addEventListener('gattserverdisconnected', onDisconnected);
    PairedBluetoothDevices.push(device);
    return { "Name": device.name, "Id": device.id };    
}

function connect(bluetoothDevice) {
    exponentialBackoff(3 /* max retries */, 1 /* seconds delay */,
        function toTry() {
            time('Connecting to Bluetooth Device... ');
            
            return bluetoothDevice.gatt.connect();
        },
        function success() {
            console.log('> Bluetooth Device connected. Try disconnect it now.');
        },
        function fail() {
            time('Failed to reconnect.');
        });
}
```

code for writing to the characteristic:

```
export async function writeValue(deviceId, serviceId, characteristicId, value)
{
    var device = getDevice(deviceId);
    console.log(device);
    if (device.gatt.connected) {
        var service = await device.gatt.getPrimaryService(serviceId);
        var characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(characteristicId);
        var b = Uint8Array.from(value);
        await characteristic.writeValueWithoutResponse(b);
    }
    else
    {
        await sleep(1000);
        await writeValue(deviceId, serviceId, characteristicId, value);
    }
}
```

I have used BTP BTVS with WireShark Bluetooth Sniffer to confirm that all request/response packages are identical byte for byte, to the working windows library based project, from the initial connection up to the point where the write response gives me the 'no access' error code.

My biggest question is if it is actually possible to establish a secure connection over the Web BLE API?

I am also interested in code suggestions I could try.

**update:**
I have tried using the 'add a device' functionality in windows Devices and Printer:

- Adding the device in windows before connecting through Web BLE results in:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: GATT operation failed for unknown reason.
      undefined
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: GATT operation failed for unknown reason.
undefined
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.<InvokeAsync>d__16`1[[Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.IJSVoidResult, Microsoft.JSInterop, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSObjectReferenceExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSObjectReference jsObjectReference, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Blazm.Bluetooth.BluetoothNavigator.SetupNotifyAsync(Device device, String serviceId, String characteristicId)
   at BlazorWebAssemblySample.Pages.Counter.Connect() in C:\project.page.razor:line 82
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

- And the same thing but without running the notify setup code results in not being able to pair through Web BLE at all.
- Pairing through Web BLE first and then trying to 'add a device' in windows results in windows not being able to find the device.
- A "funny" observation is that if I pair through Web BLE first, meaning that the characteristics value change event handler is set up and listening, and I then connect through my Windows.Devices.Bluetooth based project, then all the values read by this project will also be sent to/caught by the Web BLE listener and seen in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems a bit similar to what we have seen on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1271239. As a trial, could you try to pair the device ahead of time using [Windows system pairing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/pair-a-bluetooth-device-in-windows-2be7b51f-6ae9-b757-a3b9-95ee40c3e242#:%7E:text=To%20pair%20a%20Bluetooth%20headset%2C%20speaker%2C%20or%20other%20audio%20device&text=On%20your%20PC%2C%20select%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Devices%20%3E%20Bluetooth,they%20appear%2C%20then%20select%20Done.)? Then write to the characteristic and see if it works.

Comment: As you say it is a similar issue, because they also have a device with a protected characteristic, but they are not able to pair without windows being paired first, while I am only able to pair if windows is not paired first. I just cant read values because the connection is not considered secure by the characteristic. I have updated my initial post to try to clarify this.

Comment: Actually I think the word protected refers to having to enter a pin or key before accessing the characteristic. This is not the case for me, I just need the pairing type to be 'Just Works' for a secure connection to happen.

Comment: From your "funny Observation", it still makes me feel there is some kind of pairing issue. It might be that the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth based project help set up the pairing part properly. And pairing might have multiple type, not necessary need to type in a pin (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicepairingkinds?view=winrt-22000#fields). 

There is simple WebBluetooth read char value demo you could refer to but I guess it might see the same issue (https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/read-characteristic-value-changed-async-await.html).

Comment: If you don't mind, could you share the information of your bluetooth device?

Comment: I agree that this is definitely a pairing issue. In the windows based project I am pairing after connecting to the device, also referred to as bonding in some places. This is the step that creates the secure/encrypted connection that my device requires in order to accept read/write commands. Unfortunately I dont see any documentation on how to control the connect/pairing sequence with Web BLE. There is simply a device.gatt.connect() method and after that it is out of my hands.

Comment: My reference for poor documentation is https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/. What information about the device would you like me to share? It does not have a battery level service as required by the example you posted.

Comment: Device information like where I can acquire the same device as you have, so that I can try to reproduce the issue. We (Chrome Device team) are targeting on fixing Window pairing issue in Q2, so we are interested in having the same device that you have this issue to be used to validate if our fix can fix the issue you have.

Comment: The device is a custom device and is in the prototype phase right now, so it is not something that is obtainable and I am not allowed to share it either. But you should definitely run into this issue if you set up a device with a characteristic that has encrypted read, encrypted write and encrypted notify. If there are any specific technical specifications you need I can answer this, but I cannot share the entire specification as it is confidential. Also note that this is not only a windows problem, I tried running the web app on android with the same issue.

Comment: I have the fact the exact same issue while trying to subscribe to a gatt characteristic of a ble barcode reader. The barcode reader requires you to 'Pair' before subscription, and pairing using windows makes the device go undiscoverable. Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73505491/bluetooth-web-bonding-before-connection