# Bluetooth web Bonding before connection

Tags: blazor, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I am working on trying to get a wearable BLE barcode scanner to interact with a blazor web application(Utilizing Blazm) while using Chrome browser's Bluetooth Web capabilities.

The barcode scanner supports BLE, however it requires 'bonding' before if would let you read certain characteristics.

So even though Bluetooth web thinks It connected to the device, the device actually doesn't let me read/be notified for certain Characteristics, Hence no real data can be passed through.

Any idea how this could be sorted and if there is any way to control the bonding behavior?

(NB: I wanted to get this to work only for Chrome on Windows and Android devices).

Comment: Maybe you can bond it first using the system's Bluetooth settings?

Comment: Tried that, and if I bond/pair from the windows Bluetooth settings the device stops broadcasting it's availability and won't even shop up in browser's list of available BLE devices.

Comment: If you try to use this app : https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html?allDevices=true, when the device is bond, can you see the device in the scanning list?

Comment: Interestingly the problem has been reporte dby multiple people: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71590482/web-ble-secure-connection-with-pairing-type-just-works